# how to add wildcards to the re.sub and remove all characters before the _

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

i have the following code

```
    infile = botslib.opendata(ta_from.filename,'r')
    tofile = botslib.opendata(str(ta_to.idta),'wb')
    start = infile.readline()
    import textwrap
    import re
    lines= "\r\n".join(textwrap.wrap(start, 640))
    for line in lines:
        re.sub('^\...[_]*', '',line)
        tofile.write(line.split('_')[-1])
    infile.close()
    tofile.close()
```

the input is

**Ichg_UNBUNOA3**                                   14                2090100000015                      14                1304221445000001

the ouput now is 
**IchgUNBUNOA3**                                   14                2090100000015                      14                1304221445000001

but i expect it to be 
**UNBUNOA3**                                   14                2090100000015                      14                1304221445000001

ichg can also be grp1 grp12

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Something does not make sense in your example. The regex has `\.` which matches a period right at the beginning of the line, but your example does not start with period, and the substitution should not happen at all.

Comment: Unrelated to the previous comment. You need to try this regex `^.*?_*` on the `sub`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
print re.sub('^[^_]*_', '', 'Ichg_UNBUNOA3 14 2090100000015 14 1304221445000001')
```

explanation:

```
^ begin of the line
[^_]* all characters that are not underscore 0 or more time
_ underscore
```

you must make a choice between split (best way in my opinion) or regex (you have written the two!)

```
for line in lines:
    tofile.write(line.split('_')[-1])
```

or

```
for line in lines:
    tofile.write(re.sub('^[^_]*_', '', line))
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your `lines` variable isn't actually a list of lines - it's a single string containing the wrapped lines joined together. As a result, you're looping over the string one character at a time rather than processing one line at a time.

You need to get rid of the `"\r\n".join` call around the textwrap call and you should have the lines in a list as intended.

As for the regex: besides being wrong, that code serves no purpose, since you never actually assign the result of the `re.sub` call to anything. But it's not needed anyway, since the `split` call below achieves the same thing.

In short, your code should just look more like this:

```
infile = botslib.opendata(ta_from.filename,'r')
tofile = botslib.opendata(str(ta_to.idta),'wb')
start = infile.readline()
import textwrap
lines= textwrap.wrap(start, 640)
for line in lines:
    tofile.write(line.split('_')[-1])
infile.close()
tofile.close()
```